# Reaction of a non-metal with alkali to produce hydrogen gas

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I want to ask that is there any non-metal which reacts with an alkali (NOT alkali metal) to produce hydrogen gas?

Comment: Does silicon count as a nonmetal?  https://www.webelements.com/silicon/chemistry.html.

Answer (score 3):

By "non-metal", are you asking about elements that are not metals (that includes metalloids and non-metals) or non-metals by definition? Anyways, I'll stick to the latter. The non-metals include carbon, nitrogen, phosphorus, oxygen, sulfur, selenium, the halogens (except astatine) and the noble gases.

In short, the answer is: "non-metals that give reaction do not give hydrogen as product". We can find out by listing them:

1. Carbon: No reaction
2. Nitrogen: No reaction
3. Phosphorus: [Give phosphine](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68013/reaction-of-white-phosphorus-with-aqueous-sodium-hydroxide/68017)
4. Oxygen: No reaction
5. Sulfur: [Depending on reaction conditions, it can various polysulfide species along with sodium thiosulfate and water](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50990/reaction-between-sulfur-and-sodium-hydroxide)
6. Selenium: Might give similar reactions to sulfur (couldn't find any reference)
7. All halogens reacts with sodium hydroxide

   - Fluorine react to give oxygen(II) fluoride and fluoride ion ([webelemets](https://www.webelements.com/fluorine/chemistry.html))
     $$\ce{2F2(g) + 2OH-(aq) → OF2(g) + 2F-(aq) + H2O(l)}$$
   - Chlorine reacts with cold hydroxide to give chloride and oxychloride but with hot hydroxide it gives chlorate

$$\ce{2OH-(cold) + Cl2 -> Cl- + OCl- + H2O}$$
$$\ce{6OH-(hot) + Cl2 -> Cl- + ClO3- + H2O}$$

- - Bromine and iodine esentially give the same reactions forming bromate(V) and iodate(V) respectively ([chemguide](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/group7/otherreactions.html))

8. No noble gas reacts with sodium hydroxide

Comment: thanks for these but I asked for reaction of a NON-metal with an alkali  though these reactions will be helpful

Comment: @Shinjinee the above elements are all non-metal

Comment: ?!? Al is a metal, as is tin unless you keep it in the cold for too long.

Comment: @Karl,  they are non metal in normal conditions.

Comment: Who on earth told you that? Both are good conductors (esp. Al), ductile, have a silvery surface. Yes, neither is as perfectly a "metallic" element as sodium or iron, but to call them non-metals is utterly ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't say "aqueous", boron fused with sodium hydroxide produces hydrogen and sodium borate.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/41140)

Comment: Um... boron is a non-metal, sodium hydroxide is an alkali and hydrogen... is hydrogen.  How can this NOT be an answer to the question?

Comment: However, if I'm really picky, I'd have to admit that boron is really a metalloid, and the real non-metals (halogens + O + N + C + P + S + Se) don't produce hydrogen when fused with sodium hydroxide.  So if the OP means 'not a metal including metalloids' I'm ok...